# GoCD pull from multiple branches and deploy to different environments

Tags: go-cd

I'm right now using GoCD for automate our deployments.

These are the versions I'm using.

```
go-agent  17.10.0-5380
go-server 17.10.0-5380
```

I'd like to expose a case that I wasn't able to fix just by configuring GoCD, I couldn't find anything that can help me out on that, most likely I'm missing something ;-)

Here's the case I'd like to achive:

We have a GIT repository: `frontend-app`

In that repo every developer can push changes to different branches following this naming convention: `dev-1`, `dev-2`, ...

The goal to achive is that every time a developer pushes changes to `dev-1`, goCD will take those changes in that branch, build it and deploy to our environment `dev-1`.

If developer 2 pushes changes to `dev-2`, goCD will take those changes, build them and deploy to `dev-2` environment.

The first I've tried, to achive this, is configure the pipeline using only 1 material and try to use some glob pattern on branch names. As you can see in the attached screenshot.

[image: configure material branch glob pattern]

However I couldn't get this working.

The second thing I tried is to use multiple materials. To be able to have multiple materials you need to configure the material giving to it a specific Destination directory. As you can see in the attached screenshot:

[image: configure multiple materials with destination directory]

With this approach I was able to have goCD pulling for new changes and checking repo out on the specific Destination directory.

For my pipeline I have configured a template with a bunch of tasks to build the project, before deploying it, ie: `npm install`, `npm test`, `npm run-script build`, etc...

However, those tasks are then executed on the parent directory (`go-agent/pipelines/frontend-app/`), instead of in the Destination directory (dev-1, dev-2, ...)

```
go-agent/pipelines/frontend-app/
  |_ dev-1
  |_ dev-2
  |_ ...
```

I've been reading about goCD environment variables and I couldn't find any variable that holds the destination directory, so I could reference it in my tasks.

Of course, as a solution, you can always create several pipelines in order to achieve this, ie:

frontend-app-dev-1, frontend-app-dev-2, etc...

But my problem is that I have 8 dev environments and also 10 projects. So as you can imagine is quite a job to configure all those things separately.

Specially if later we make any change, that's a lot of work to do it manually and prone to errors.

So my questions are:

1. in case the first approach (branch glob pattern), can this goal be achieved by using Branch glob pattern ?
2. if we use second approach (several materials), Does someone know if this can be achieved ? I think I'm almost there, but probably I'm missing something when configuring my tasks.
3. Any other ideas to be able to get this working ?
4. Is there any other way to achieve the things I need ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You really need a pipeline per branch. Each commit triggers a new instance of a pipeline, and if you handle several branches in one pipeline, the history view doesn't distinguish the branches, and you get a jumble of disconnected commits there.

To reduce the configuration overhead, you could use GoCD's [pipelines as code](https://docs.gocd.org/current/advanced_usage/pipelines_as_code.html) feature to write the pipelines as data structures to a git repo, and you can [use templating to generate that repo](https://github.com/tomzo/gocd-json-config-plugin/wiki/Template-Experiment).

The GoCD team [considers using such templates to implement wildcard branch support](https://github.com/gocd/gocd/issues/5675#issuecomment-496999209), but it's not yet done.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible for the pipeline to checkout a repo that contains your custom build files and then run those... with the idea being that your custom build files handle the actual repo you want to build out of, including selection of branches.   I've done this with taskfiles (taskfile.dev), but sometimes you have to step back and see if what you're doing is truly the best way.

You might also checkout the plugin "Build Git Feature Branches", which may or may not do what you want.